# osgi LinkageError issue

Tags: java, osgi, osgi-bundle, apache-servicemix

I'm struggling with the dreaded java.lang.LinkageError. Here's what I'm trying to do. Bundle A consists of a class TestA which is calling a method in class TestB, hosted in Bundle B. As part of the method call, TestA is passing a Solrj class (org.apache.solr.common.SolrInputDocument) to TestB. Here's the pom configuration.

## Bundle B pom

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.1</version>
   <extensions>true</extensions>
   <configuration>
      <instructions>
         <Export-Package>com.test.solr.api;version=1.1.0, 
                                                        org.apache.solr.common.*, 
                                                        org.apache.solr.client, 
                                                        org.apache.solr.client.solrj;</Export-Package>
         <Import-Package>com.test.model.*;version="[1.0.0,2.0.0)", 
                                                        *;resolution:=optional</Import-Package>
         <Embed-Dependency>solr-solrj,zookeeper,httpcore,httpmime,httpclient,commons-collections,commons-lang,commons-collections,commons-io,commons-logging;scope=compile|runtime</Embed-Dependency>
         <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
         <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
         <Bundle-Version>${project.version}</Bundle-Version>
         <Bundle-ClassPath>.,{maven-dependencies}</Bundle-ClassPath>
         <Include-Resource>{maven-resources}, {maven-dependencies}</Include-Resource>
      </instructions>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

## Bundle A pom

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <instructions>
            <Export-Package>com.test.postprocess.api;version="[1.0.0,2.0.0)",</Export-Package>
            <Import-Package>com.test.solr.api;version="[1.0.0,2.0.0)", 
                                                        javax.jws, 
                                                        javax.wsdl, 
                                                        javax.xml.bind, 
                                                        javax.xml.bind.annotation, 
                                                        javax.xml.namespace, 
                                                        javax.xml.ws, 
                                                        META-INF.cxf, 
                                                        META-INF.cxf.osgi, 
                                                        org.apache.cxf.bus, 
                                                        org.apache.cxf.bus.spring, 
                                                        org.apache.cxf.bus.resource, 
                                                        org.apache.cxf.configuration.spring, 
                                                        org.apache.cxf.resource, 
                                                        org.apache.cxf.jaxws, 
                                                        org.apache.cxf.transport.http, 
                                                        !org.jvnet.staxex, 
                                                        !org.relaxng.datatype, 
                                                        !com.sun.javadoc, 
                                                        !com.caucho.burlap., 
                                                        org.apache.solr., 
                                                        org.w3c.dom, 
                                                        org.apache.xpath.jaxp, 
                                                        ;resolution:=optional</Import-Package>
            <Embed-Dependency>commons-codec,xstream,commons-io,httpcore,httpclient,httpmime;scope=compile|runtime</Embed-Dependency>
            <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
            <Bundle-Version>${project.version}</Bundle-Version>
            <Bundle-ClassPath>.,{maven-dependencies}</Bundle-ClassPath>
            <Include-Resource>{maven-resources}, {maven-dependencies}</Include-Resource>
        </instructions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

As you can see, I'm exporting org.apache.solr.common., org.apache.solr.client and org.apache.solr.client.solrj package in bundle B, which is being imported in bundle A.

But I'm getting the following runtime exception.

**java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/apache/felix/framework/ModuleImpl$ModuleClassLoaderJava5) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/apache/solr/common/SolrInputDocument"**

Not sure what I'm missing. I'm using servicemix 4.4.0.

Any pointer will be highly appreciated.

-Thanks,